# ListView Move Item with Up and Down Button .NET Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-4.0

I have a problem!

I have a listview that will have a random number of items (according to the pages of a document). But I need to have the option to reorder these pages (which are the listview items). I did a function to use on both buttons (Up and Down) but it is not reordering right. For example: I have two items (Page 1 and Page 2) and I want to move Page 2 to position 0, it moves but in listview it still displays the previous order. Among other examples I made with more pages.
Below is the code and his call.

```
private void moveImgList(int direction)
    {
        if (list_image.SelectedItems == null) { return; }

        ListViewItem item = list_image.SelectedItems[0];

        int newIndex = item.Index + direction;

        if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= list_image.Items.Count) { return; }

        list_image.Items.Remove(item);
        list_image.Items.Insert(newIndex, item);

    }
```

Method call

```
private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.moveImgList(-1);
    }

    private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.moveImgList(1);
    }
```

Application Windows Form .NET Framework

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAFSc.jpg)

**It worked that way!**

```
private void moveItem(int direction)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0) { return; }

        ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

        int newIndex = item.Index + direction;

        if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= listView1.Items.Count) { return; }

        var currentView = listView1.View;
        listView1.BeginUpdate();
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Items.Remove(item);
        listView1.Items.Insert(newIndex, item);
        listView1.EnsureVisible(newIndex);
        listView1.View = currentView;
        listView1.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: Your code works as expected. Performing the index change in a `BeginUpdate()`  `EndUpdate()` sequence just eliminates the flickering. Remove `Refresh()`, it's not required.

Comment: You could add `list_image.Focus();` in the Buttons `Click` event after the `moveImgList()` call (to better see the index change: the selected item will remain visibly selected).

Comment: I put `list_image.Focus ();`, but it didn't work either. I still have the same problem

Comment: This is [your code at work](https://imgur.com/aiYwaxz), I just added `list_image.EnsureVisible(newIndex);`. What is wrong with it?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/IddRTsu) This is my code working here

Comment: Ah, in non-Details view. Try like this: `var currentView = list_image.View; list_image.BeginUpdate(); list_image.View = View.Details; list_image.Items.Remove(item); list_image.Items.Insert(newIndex, item); list_image.EnsureVisible(newIndex); list_image.View = currentView; list_image.EndUpdate();`

Comment: Good! It functioning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` method on your list view object. This forces the UI to repaint the control.

```
 list_image.BeginUpdate();
 list_image.Items.Remove(item);
 list_image.Items.Insert(newIndex, item);
 list_image.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Also adds BeginUpdate () and EndUpdate (). Unsuccessfully, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an item indexes change and you may insert in the wrong place or even get an exception if it is the last item. swapping 2 items is better I think:

```
private void moveImgList(int direction)
{
    if (list_image.SelectedItems == null) return; 
    int index = list_image.SelectedIndex;
    if((direction == -1 && index == 0) || (index == list_image.Items.Count - 1 && direction =1)
        return;
    int newIndex = index + direction;
    tmp = list_image.Items[index].Clone();
    list_image.Items[index] = (ListViewItem)list_image.Items[newIndex].Clone();
    list_image.Items[newIndex] = (ListViewItem)tmp;
}
```

And then this would work:

```
private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    moveImgList(-1);
}

private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    moveImgList(1);
}
```

Comment: Error: _System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot add or insert item' Page 1 'in more than one location. First you need to remove it from the current location or clone it._

Comment: Are you sure? because this code neither adds nor inserts

Comment: and you are using `moveImgList(-1);` and `moveImgList(1);`?

Comment: I had to make some modifications to the compile code, but at the time of execution gives the error I mentioned

Comment: `if (list_image.SelectedItems == null) return;

            ListViewItem item = list_image.SelectedItems[0];
            int index = item.Index;
            if ((direction == -1 && index == 0) || (index == list_image.Items.Count - 1 && direction == 1))
                return;
            int newIndex = index + direction;
            ListViewItem tmp = list_image.Items[index];
            list_image.Items[index] = list_image.Items[newIndex];
            list_image.Items[newIndex] = tmp;`

Comment: but please try it without modifications

Comment: Just changed 
`int index = list_image.SelectedIndex;` for 
`ListViewItem item = list_image.SelectedItems [0];
            int index = item.Index;`

Comment: And add type to variable `var tmp = list_image.Items[index];`

Comment: Line Error: `list_image.Items[index] = list_image.Items[newIndex];`

Comment: OK! No mistakes. But I still have the same problem as the question!

Comment: It's like not updating the list view. In the list items is the change, but not in the preview.

Comment: _It moves but in listview it still displays the previous order._